# get all rows having common parents

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

```
id  parent_id child_id
1    1               1
2    2               2
3    2               2
4    1               1
```

I have a table from which i need to get the common values from data when i query it with id... for eg if id=2 and id=3 then return

```
id  parent_id
2    2
3    2
```

i have tried this after hunting a lot through various examples :

```
SELECT ta.user_id,ta.interest_parent_id,ta.interest_child_id 
       FROM user_interest ta 
       WHERE ta.user_id=2 AND 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_interest tb 
            WHERE ta.interest_parent_id=tb.interest_parent_id
            AND tb.user_id=3 )>1
```

but it responds with only:

```
id  parent_id
2    2
```

any help :( im using a mysql database with php/codeigniter to do the scripting

Comment: Please elaborate your question. From what it seems with your dataset, you want to select a row with a given ID as long as the row with that particular parent ID. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: **I have a table from which i need to get the common values from data when i query it with id.** Explain this

Comment: ideally i want to pass two ids and check two rows and return the columns which having equal values

Comment: Let me know if I understood clearly: You are passing two Ids and want result only if they have the same parent?

Comment: yes that is correct.. sorry about not editing the title yet.. im more of a lurker.. i cant seem to find how to do it...

Comment: Do you want the result in two separate rows or in one row like `2 2 3 2
`

Comment: separate rows as i need the count of the total number of equal values... im using a row_count on the generated result

Comment: One more question: A single id can have multiple parents or exactly one parent?

Comment: yes the only unique column is id.. there can be multiple parents and child for a single id

Comment: if `id` is unique then how on earth it can have multiple parents/childs? Please check this [**input**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/19065022/) and let me know if it's a valid one.

Comment: yikes you got me there... i have an index column... thats the unique coulmn not id... sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
tOne.id,
tOne.parent_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM user_interest A 
    WHERE A.id IN (2,3) 
) tOne
INNER JOIN 

(
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM user_interest A 
    WHERE A.id IN (2,3) 

) tTwo
ON tOne.parent_id = tTwo.parent_id
AND tOne.id <> tTwo.id
ORDER BY tOne.parent_id;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3f407/2/0)

***Any suggestion towards optimization of the query is welcome.***

**EDIT**: [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df87/4/0)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df87/1/0          in this case it is giving me a duplicate row for the id 2.. is it because we are using a union?

Comment: Look at the last two insert statements. `INSERT INTO `user_interest` VALUES ('3', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `user_interest` VALUES ('3', '2', '1');` Same parent_id twice for id = 3

Comment: ok great... so to get the count i'm running a SELECT DISTINCT in the query you suggested and then dividing row count by 2 to get the final number of different parent_ids for a corresponding user_id... thanks a lot!

Comment: I've modified the title of your question to make it relate to the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a sub SELECT:

```php
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM table GROUP BY Name HAVING count(*) > 1)
```